# S3 bucket content is not getting listed till last

Tags: php, foreach, amazon-s3

I started listing the contents of a S3 bucket using foreach loop.

```
$contents = $s3->getBucket("bucket-name");
foreach($contents as $value) 
    {
      print $value['name']; echo "<br>"; 
    }
```

But the problem is that it is not listing above 1000 index. The last few files are not listing. 
I tried getting the length of the array and I found that last few files are not even getting stored in that array.

What should I do to list them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default number of listed files is set to 1000, so thats why you cannot get more than 1000 files:

Here you have a description of a function:

```
public static function getBucket($bucket, $prefix = null, $marker = null, $maxKeys = null, $delimiter = null) {
```

Use `$marker` to set where to start getting files and `$maxKeys` as a limit.

Comment: Amazon limits its response to max 1000 objects, as stated in the documentation. Higher values for $maxkey will not work here.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [S3 developer documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html):

> As buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, Amazon S3 API support pagination to split them into
>   multiple responses. Each list keys response returns a page of up to
>   1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is truncated.
>   You send a series of list keys requests until you have received all
>   the keys. AWS SDK wrapper libraries provide the same pagination.

That means you need multi page requests to iterate over multiple "pages". This will depend on the implementation of your "s3"-Class. Which library are you using for s3?

If the implementation you are using offers a **"getBucket"**-Method, there will be an optional parameter **$marker**. Place here the key of the last object to retrieve the next 1000 objects after that object.

Documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: This is the method in my S3 library file. [public static function getBucket($bucket, $prefix = null, $marker = null, $maxKeys = null) ]. What change should I make?

Comment: With your first request you get 1000 object-keys. Take the last one and pass this as parameter for $marker on your second request to retrieve the next 1000 (max) objects

Comment: I'm totally new to this. Can you please edit the above code @  itinance

Comment: To be honestly, as a developer you should be able to call a method with a second parameter and also to read and understand documentation :) Stackoverflow is a platform to give you hints and answer your questions, not to do your work in general

Comment: I got it. I used iterator method.