# "specified pipeline was not found" in amazon elastic transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am trying to use amazon elastic transcoder to transcode a job, but it keeps on giving me the following error:

> /gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.66.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:375:in `return_or_raise':
>   The specified pipeline was not found: account=XXXXXXXXX,
>   pipelineId=xxxxxxxxx. (AWS::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::ResourceNotFoundException)

My simplified code is as follows:

```
transcoder = AWS::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new(
  region: "us-west-1",
  access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_KEY
)

transcoder.create_job(
  pipeline_id: '0123456789123-sample",
  input: {
    key: "input_key.mp4",
    frame_rate: 'auto',
    resolution: 'auto',
    aspect_ratio: 'auto',
    interlaced: 'auto',
    container: 'auto'
  },
  output: {
    key: "output_key.mp4",
    preset_id: '1351620000001-000010'
  }
)
```

I checked online and found a couple of resources, specifically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815250/amazon-s3-elastic-transcoder-error-the-specified-pipeline-was-not-found) and [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116712)

Both basically say that the pipeline region and the "create job region" must match exactly. The pipeline I created in the amazon management console, I verified, is "Northern California" ("us-west-1"), and it seems to log in ok with the script. However, I don't know where, specifically to set the region in the "transcoder.create_job" part. Does anyone know? i can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I figured out what was wrong. I had the wrong pipeline_id in my
script. You can click on the little icon of a piece of paper with a magnifying glass on the pipelines screen in the aws admin panel to find the pipeline_id. I put that id in my CreateJob script, and voila, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the boto3 sdk for Python and was getting the same error. It looks like the default region name on my server was different than my pipeline's. What I did was add the region_name parameter and add the pipeline's region.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elastictranscoder', region_name='us-west-2')
list_pipelines = client.list_pipelines()

print list_pipelines
```